# Open Files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm using Eclipse Mars with the TFS plugin. I work with many files that don't have a file extension. Is there a setting to have those files open in Eclipse? Currently, I always get Windows "what do you want to do with this file" selection displays.

All of these non-extension files are plain text that would properly render in Eclipse.

Comment: What do you mean with "have those file open in Eclipse"? Are you opening them from Windows Explorer or from somewhere in Eclipse?

Comment: In the source control explorer displayed in Eclipse. If you double-click a file it will use the default program associated. 

For example, in Visual Studio, if you open a file it will attempt to open in Visual Studio first. That is what I'm trying to configure in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob:
Unfortunately, the way our Eclipse TFS plugin (i.e. TEE) is written today, you will not be able to do what you are asking (meaning, you will not be able to configure the system so that when you click on a file with no file extension in the source control explorer and have it open in Eclipse – you will always be promoted by Windows to choose the application).  We will keep this use case in mind as we continue to support the plug-in and will add it to the backlog of options to be considered in the next release.  We are sorry for any inconvenience this is causing you.  Thank you for your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We are working on applying file extensions to these types of files so it shouldn't be an issue for us for long. Would still love to see this feature down the road, so thank for considering it.

Answer (score 1):

We have a fix in TEE/Eclipse TFS plugin to handle opening files without any extensions from Source Control Explorer in Eclipse. It will be available with our next update.

Thanks,
Madhuri